# Strange see-through pane on top of everything

Tags: appearance

I have just suddenly noticed that there is a strange see-through pane that goes on top of everything, there is not way to move it, close it, or move anything in front of it, it looks like this:

[image: Strange see-through pane]

So, what is it, and how do I get rid of it as it is rather annoying? And seems to have just appeared for no reason...

**Information Update:**

On one of the occasions this happened, it was after closing a Steam window, and what fixed that was to restart Steam, but I can't restart everything, so a more long-term fix would be greatly appreciated.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Extra Inforamtion:**

I am using Unity on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mateo can you absolutely 100% verify the OP is using Unity?

Comment: talked to him in chat ;)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22617679#22617679

Comment: @Mateo OK, there was no reference to that in the edit msg, so it appeared as a "What are you doing?  Can you confirm this?" thing.  Thanks for posting the transcript, I was about to rollback your edit xD